# Ethernet Bridge to Xen VM not working

Tags: networking, virtualization, bridge, xen

i'm using Ubuntu 18.04 to run a windows 7 instance in Xen. 
But the issue is i don't get any internet in the windows7 guest, in dom0 it's working fine.
Here is my netplan yaml:

```
# Let networkd manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
  #declare the interface used y the bridge device
    enp0s25:
     dhcp4: no
  bridges:
    xenbr0:
      dhcp4: yes
      interfaces:
       - enp0s25
```

brctl show confirmes that the bridge is up and bound to my ethernet interface:

```
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
docker0     8000.02422948448e   no      
xenbr0      8000.32d6f9443e7a   no      enp0s25
```

I dont really know how to troubleshoot this at all so any pointers are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out I removed the vif config entry from my xen config at some point. 
Adding the bridge to the config fixed it.